# How to set title for header section from the properties of INDEXPATH.ROW

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

i get a response from API like this:

```
[{
  "name":"apple"
   "type": "Fruit"
     "taste": sweet

    }
  {
    "name":"lemon"
   "type": "Fruit"
 "taste": "not tasty"
 }]
```

and now i want to set the title of the section as **name** of UITable view.

for this i have called this in my view controller as:

```
 var modelclass = [FruitsModelclass]()

 override func viewDidLoad()
{
self.loaddata()
}

func loaddata()
{
 //here i have called the API and sucessfully get the response in data and assign as

    self.modelclass = data
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?) -> UITableViewCell? {
  let cell = tableView!.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath!) as FruitCell
    let model = self.Modeldata[indexpath.row]
     cell.textlabel.text = model.name
    return cell
}
```

this is how i set the **name** to cell.How can i set this to my headerSection..??there are alot of json objects in my Api its not fixed one. Here i have presented only two in can anyone help me out..??

Comment: what kind of data do you want to render in tableview's header?

Comment: I presume you have all the tableView delegate methods set before you try doing any of this? i.e numberOfRowsInSection, numberOfSections and override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String?

Comment: yes i have both of them but please guide me how can i do that

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to add title...

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return "SOME TEXT" //return your text here, may be 
}
```

if you want control over header view then something like this

```
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat{
        return 50 //height you want of section
    }
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?{

        let vw = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: 50)) 
//view for header, you can also use view from nib, but thats another matter
        vw.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.size.width-10, height: 50)) 
//add label or buttons or what ever u want to view....
        label.text = “SOME TEXT“

        vw.addSubview(label)

        return vw
    }
```

And as a side note numberOfSections is imp to show headers

Comment: where did you set the name as section header,??

Comment: you need to replace "SOME TEXT" with whatever section name you need

Comment: maybe you can upload part of code you are facing issue to github and share here it would be easier